# How to join tables with different periodicity

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables, one is for **measurements** and every 3 seconds or so a value is written in a very simple structure:

Measurements:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1679474929 | 516 |
| 1679474933 | 501 |
| 1679474936 | 505 |

While the **second contains all meta information**, trigger values, etc. This one is changed sporadically, but randomly. Meta information is valid from the moment of change to a different change that would be sometimes a week and sometimes a month. Thousands of measurements are done between each change.

What I need is to JOIN them together in the way that all the measurements would have meta information from a relevant period in the meta table.

I'm imagining some sort of conditional comparison, something like this.

First, try:

`ON measurements.timestamp=meta.timestamp`

then

`ON DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(measurements.timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')=DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta.timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')`

then

`ON DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(measurements.timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d %H')=DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta.timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d %H')`

then

`ON DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(measurements.timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta.timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d')`

etc. until the condition is satisfied.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using the [LEAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to get the value of the next `meta` row's `timestamp`:

```
SELECT *
FROM measurements
JOIN (
    SELECT *, LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS next_timestamp
    FROM meta
) meta
    ON measurements.timestamp >= meta.timestamp
    AND (
        measurements.timestamp < meta.next_timestamp OR
        meta.next_timestamp IS NULL
    )
```

It may be worth testing the performance of the [lateral derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) version of Bernd's solution, if you want to return multiple columns from `meta`:

```
SELECT *
FROM measurements
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM meta
    WHERE measurements.timestamp >= meta.timestamp
    ORDER BY meta.timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
) m;
```

Answer (score 1):

did you mean something like this ?

```
SELECT mea.*
 ,( SELECT meta from meta WHERE meta.ts <= mea.ts ORDER by meta.ts DESC LIMIT 1) as meta
FROM `Measurements` mea;
```

** Sample **

```
mysql> SELECT * from Measurements;
+----+------------+------+
| id | ts         | val  |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 1679474929 |  516 |
|  2 | 1679474933 |  501 |
|  3 | 1679474936 |  505 |
+----+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from meta;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | ts         | meta        |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 1679474920 | First meta  |
|  2 | 1679474935 | Second Meta |
+----+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT mea.*, ( SELECT meta from meta WHERE meta.ts <= mea.ts ORDER by meta.ts DESC LIMIT 1) as meta
    -> FROM `Measurements` mea;
+----+------------+------+-------------+
| id | ts         | val  | meta        |
+----+------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | 1679474929 |  516 | First meta  |
|  2 | 1679474933 |  501 | First meta  |
|  3 | 1679474936 |  505 | Second Meta |
+----+------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This one works too. Thank you!